# Vectorizing nested ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to fasten my function in R. It contains of three ifelse statements where one of it is nested. For the single one I conducted vectorization which reduced my computation time. Unfortunately I don't see how I can vectorize the nested one. Every way I apply it returns an error. Furthemore if there is any another quirk I can use to speed it up?

```
cont.run <- function(reps=10000, n=10000, d=0.005, l=10 ,s=0.1) {
  r <- rep(0, reps)
  theta <- rep(0, n)
  for (t in 1:reps) {
    epsilon <- rnorm(1, 0, d)
    Zt = sum(ifelse(epsilon > theta, 1, 
                ifelse(epsilon < -theta, -1, 0)))
    r[t] <- Zt / (l * n)
    theta <- ifelse(runif(n) < s, abs(r[t]), theta)
  }
  return(mean(r))
}

system.time(cont.run())
```

I got:

```
cont.run <- function(reps=10000, n=10000, d=0.005, l=10 ,s=0.1) {
  r <- rep(0, reps)
  theta <- rep(0, n)
  for (t in 1:reps) {
    epsilon <- rnorm(1, 0, d)
    Zt = rep(NA, length(theta))
    Zt = sum(Zt[epsilon > theta, 1])
    Zt = sum(Zt[epsilon < -theta, -1])
    r[t] <- Zt / (l * n)
    theta = rep(theta, length(s))
    theta[runif(n)  < s] = abs(r[t])  
  }
  return(mean(r))
}

system.time(cont.run())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little bit improved code.
Main change is that we don't use double `ifelse`, but instead perform two sums on `TRUE` vectors (`sum(epsilon > theta) - sum(epsilon < -theta)`) (we don't care about zeroes here). I added a couple of other improvements (eg., replaced `rep` with `numeric`, moved some operations outside the `for` loop).

```
contRun <- function(reps = 1e4, n = 1e4, d = 5e-3, l = 10, s = 0.1) {
    # Replace rep with numeric
    r <- numeric(reps)
    theta <- numeric(n)    
    # Define before loop
    ln <- l * n
    # Don't use t as it's a function in base R
    for (i in 1:reps) {
        epsilon <- rnorm(1, 0, d)
        # Sum two TRUE vectors
        r[i] <- (sum(epsilon > theta) - sum(epsilon < -theta)) / ln
        # Define before ifelse
        absr <- abs(r[i])
        theta <- ifelse(runif(n) < s, absr, theta)
    }
    return(mean(r))
}
```

---

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(cont.run(), contRun())

Unit: seconds                       
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 cont.run() 13.652324 13.749841 13.769848 13.766342 13.791573 13.853786   100
  contRun()  6.533654  6.559969  6.581068  6.577265  6.596459  6.770318   100
```

---

PS. For this kind of computing you might one to set seed (`set.seed()` before the `for` loop) to make sure that you can reproduce your results.

Comment: Thank you sir! I'll keep those tips in my mind. Can you provide extra explanation/paper/anything on performing two sums on true vectors? It seems interesting, actually never heard of it.

Comment: @Tom `>` returns a TRUE/FALSE vector (TRUE is equivalent to 1) and you can sum it.  You wanted 1 for `epsilon > theta` and we're getting it with `sum(epsilon > theta)`; you wanted `-1` for `epsilon < -theta` and we're getting it with `- sum(epsilon < -theta)`

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to achieve. By the way do you know how I can conduct vectorization on this nested ifelse wrapped in sum?

Comment: @Tom what do you mean by *this nested ifelse wrapped in sum*?

Comment: My bad. I misused terms. I'd like to do the same thing with the nested ifelse as I did with the single one. I understand it's less efficient but I'd like to see how it can look like.

Comment: @Tom I don't understand. But this is what I posted. `sum(epsilon > theta)` gives you ones (what you wanted to do with `sum(Zt[epsilon > theta, 1])`). `sum(epsilon < -theta)` gives you minus ones. Error from your code came from `Zt = sum(Zt[epsilon > theta, 1])` - here you turn `Zt` into one number (because you use `sum`) and following step (`Zt[epsilon < -theta, -1]`) doesn't make sense as it's not vector anymore.

Answer (score 1):

> Furthemore if there is any another quirk I can use to speed it up?

In addition to [PoGibas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54158747/5861244) answer, you can avoid calling `ifelse` and get a faster function as follows

```r
contRun <- function(reps = 1e4, n = 1e4, d = 5e-3, l = 10, s = 0.1) {
  # Replace rep with numeric
  r <- numeric(reps)
  theta <- numeric(n)    
  # Define before loop
  ln <- l * n
  # Don't use t as it's a function in base R
  for (i in 1:reps) {
    epsilon <- rnorm(1, 0, d)
    # Sum two TRUE vectors
    r[i] <- (sum(epsilon > theta) - sum(epsilon < -theta)) / ln
    # Define before ifelse
    absr <- abs(r[i])
    theta <- ifelse(runif(n) < s, absr, theta)
  }
  mean(r)
}

contRun2 <- function(reps = 1e4, n = 1e4, d = 5e-3, l = 10, s = 0.1) {
  r <- numeric(reps)
  theta <- numeric(n)    
  ln <- l * n
  for (i in 1:reps) {
    epsilon <- rnorm(1, 0, d)
    r[i] <- (sum(epsilon > theta) - sum(epsilon < -theta)) / ln
    absr <- abs(r[i])
    # avoid ifelse
    theta[runif(n) < s] <- absr
  }
  mean(r)
}

contRun3 <- function(reps = 1e4, n = 1e4, d = 5e-3, l = 10, s = 0.1) {
  r <- numeric(reps)
  theta <- numeric(n)    
  ln <- l * n
  for (i in 1:reps) {
    epsilon <- rnorm(1, 0, d)
    r[i] <- (sum(epsilon > theta) - sum(epsilon < -theta)) / ln
    absr <- abs(r[i])
    # replace runif
    theta[sample(c(T, F), prob = c(s, 1 - s), size = n, replace = TRUE)] <- absr
  }
  mean(r)
}

# gives the same
set.seed(1)
o1 <- contRun()
set.seed(1)
o2 <- contRun2()
set.seed(1)
o3 <- contRun3()

all.equal(o1, o2)
#R [1] TRUE
all.equal(o1, o3) # likely will not match
#R [1] [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.1508537"

# but distribution is the same
set.seed(1)
c1 <- replicate(10000, contRun2(reps = 100, n = 100))
c2 <- replicate(10000, contRun3(reps = 100, n = 100))
par(mfcol = c(1, 2), mar = c(5, 4, 2, .5))
hist(c1, breaks = seq(-.015, .015, length.out = 26))
hist(c2, breaks = seq(-.015, .015, length.out = 26))
```

[image]

```
# the latter is faster
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  contRun  = {set.seed(1); contRun ()}, 
  contRun2 = {set.seed(1); contRun2()},
  contRun3 = {set.seed(1); contRun3()},
  times = 5)
#R Unit: seconds
#R      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#R   contRun 7.121264 7.371242 7.388159 7.384997 7.443940 7.619352     5
#R  contRun2 3.811267 3.887971 3.892523 3.892158 3.921148 3.950070     5
#R  contRun3 1.920594 1.920754 1.998829 1.999755 2.009035 2.144005     5
```

The only bottleneck now is `runif` in `contRun2`. Replacing it with `sample` yields quite an improvement.